# Regex pattern needed for this example: 99999999/99 DD/MM/YYYY

Tags: javascript, regex, reactjs, input-mask

First 10 digits with space is working fine but my date regex is failing.

```
^(\d{6}\s{2}|\d{8})\/(\d{1}\s|\d{2})\s\/(?:(?:31(\/|-|\.)(?:0?[13578]|1[02]))\1|(?:(?:29|30)(\/|-|\.)(?:0?[1,3-9]|1[0-2])\2))(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2})$|^(?:29(\/|-|\.)0?2\3(?:(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?(?:0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|(?:(?:16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00))))$|^(?:0?[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])(\/|-|\.)(?:(?:0?[1-9])|(?:1[0-2]))\4(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2})$
```

Comment: what is this input and are you looking at regex only solution?

Comment: Your date regex seems way too complex. There is obvioulsy simpler ways to do it, please make some research.

Comment: That's one nasty monster regex.

Comment: Thanks all , I tried other approaches using react-input-mask but there is no luck. Earlier tried with ^(\d{6}\s{2}|\d{8})/(\d{1}\s|\d{2})\s\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}$ now all i need in date regex to be added for the above one.

Comment: But you haven't told us what you want to validate and what is acceptance criterion?

Comment: 6 to 8 digits with spaces allowed (999  9 99) "/" two digits (99)" "DD/MM/YYYY in date DD must be below or equal 31 , MM must be 12 or below and YYYY can be anything but must be 4 digits. @gurvinder372

Answer (score 0):

Got a Solution But where feb must be 28/29 days apart from this all others are working please look at the pattern

^([0-9]{6}|[0-9]{8})([\s]{2}|[\s]{0})[/]{1}[0-9]{2}[\s]{1}(0[0-9]|[0-2]|1[0-2])[/]{1}([0-9]|[0-2][0-9]|3[0-1])[/]{1}[0-9]{4}$